# Discord Bot Python. I'm trying to get my bot to see a command from a user, then take the next message content (will always be a bot)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I know how to take a triggering message's content, but not the next.

[image: My current code snippet]

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('&trade'):
```

I then want my code to read take the *next* message's content instead of the message that triggers the event. After the **&trade** command, a different bot will always immediately respond with a message, so it will always be the next message with content.

Comment: There is literally a method in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Here you basically need to wait until the next message by the author

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$greet'):
        channel = message.channel
        author = message.author
        await channel.send('Say hello!')

        def check(m):
            return m.author == author  and m.channel == channel

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await channel.send('Hello {.author}!'.format(msg))
```

This code basically checks the next message by the author, and returns the message's author.
For more info check out the docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try setting a variable and checking if it's set every time a user sends a message?

```py
trade = False

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  global trade

  if trade:
    #Here's the message content that you wanted
    trade = False
    return

  if message.content.startswith('&trade'):
    trade = True
```